# A more clean way to put items into grid and adjacent boxes?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of array of arrays that represents a grid. In this case a 2x3 grid, the size of the grid is based on the size of the window.

```
let grid = [
  [[], [], [],],//row
  [[], [], [],] //row
]
```

I want to put references to `this` in the cells, and the neighboring cells, based on their position. This is the best I've come up with, but it already feels clunky. What would be a more clean solution?

```
getCell(pos, arr, type){
  console.log(type, pos, arr.length)
  if(pos >= arr.length){
    return 0
  }
  if(pos < 0){
    return arr.length-1
  }
  return pos
}

setNearby(grid) {
  let col = Math.floor(this.position.y / grid.dimensions.height),
      row = Math.floor(this.position.x / grid.dimensions.width),
      offset = [-1, 0, 1];
  offset.forEach((rowOffset) => {
    offset.forEach((colOffset)=>{
      let pushRow = this.getCell(row+rowOffset, grid.grid)
      let pushCol = this.getCell(col+colOffset, grid.grid[pushRow])
      grid.grid[pushRow][pushCol].push(this)
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: First, if your solution works and objective of this post is cleaner/ more efficient code, codeReviews is the right platform for it. Apart from that, your question is a bit unclear. Please explain what exactly are you trying to achieve

Comment: Can you please clarify more what you are trying to do when you say "I want to put references to `this` in the cells, and the neighboring cells, based on their position"?

Comment: And Where is the css?

Comment: @Omer: What CSS?

Comment: @RashadSaleh basically what the code does, it pushes `this` into the cell and all neighbouring cells.